# Nesting Promises Is Not Working (jquery + League of Legends API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I want to do some practice coding with the League of Legends API. In order to do so, you first need two pieces of information: A patch version (ex. "7.12.1"), and the champion data (JSON).

The problem that I am having is that even with my nested promises, GetData() is not waiting for GetPatch() to resolve.

```js
  var URL = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/"
  var patch, data

  var GetPatch = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.getJSON(URL + "api/versions.json", f = x => {
      patch = x[0]
      console.log("patch version: " + patch)
      resolve()
    })
  })

  var GetData = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    $.getJSON(URL + "cdn/" + patch + "/data/en_US/champion.json", g = x => {
      data = x.data
      console.log(data)
      resolve()
    })
  })

  GetPatch.then(function() {
    GetData.then(function() {
      RunApp()
    })
  })

  function RunApp() {
    console.log("everything is working")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you know that jQuery AJAX functions like `$.getJSON` etc already return a Promise  - also remove `f =` and `g =` ... just use `x =>`

Comment: and, the way you are creating the promises means they will run the getJSON in "parallel"

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jaromanda on arrow functions.

How would I properly set up the `$.getJSON` functions then?

I'd like to give you the best answer if you can show me how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, jQuery AJAX functions like $.AJAX already return a promise

Secondly, the way you are setting up the promises, you are running the $.getJSON immediately

Your code could be something like - note the lack of `var patch, data`

```
var URL = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/"

var GetPatch = function() {
    return $.getJSON(URL + "api/versions.json").then(x => x[0]);
})

var GetData = function (patch) {
    return $.getJSON(URL + "cdn/" + patch + "/data/en_US/champion.json").then(x => ({patch: patch, data: x.data}));
})

GetPatch()
.then(GetData)
.then(RunApp);

function RunApp({patch, data}) {
    // here you can access patch and data if you need to
    console.log("everything is working")
}
```

If you only need `data` in `RunApp`

```
return $.getJSON(URL + "cdn/" + patch + "/data/en_US/champion.json").then(x => x.data);
...
function RunApp(data) {
    // here you can access data
    console.log("everything is working")
}
```

Another alternative - possibly "neater"

```
var URL = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/"

var GetPatch = function() {
    return $.getJSON(URL + "api/versions.json");
})

var GetData = function (patch) {
    // note the patch[0] below
    return $.getJSON(URL + "cdn/" + patch[0] + "/data/en_US/champion.json");
})

GetPatch()
.then(GetData)
.then(RunApp);

function RunApp(result) {
    // result.data is what x.data was in your code
    console.log("everything is working")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your simple and effective solution!